# initialising NSInputStream from a particular portion of file (copied in Document directory)?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, nsinputstream

I am uploading a large file from my iOS app and file transfer is in chunk upload. i am using the below code to initialise NSInputStream for Chunks.

// for example

```
NSInteger chunkCount =  20;
for(int i=0; i<chunkCount; i++) {
  NSFileHandle *handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];
  [handle seekToFileOffset:(unsigned long long)i * (chunkCount == 1?fileSize:chunkSize)];
  NSData *fileData = [handle readDataOfLength:chunkSize];
  NSInputStream *iStream = [[NSInputStream alloc]initWithData:fileData];
  }
```

But I'd like to know if I can have a method of NSInputStream by which i can initialise iStream from the range of file Stream rather than NSData.

Thanks

Comment: Theoretically you could subclass NSInputStream, but that seems to be tricky, see http://bjhomer.blogspot.de/2011/04/subclassing-nsinputstream.html.

Answer (score 1):

There is NSStreamFileCurrentOffsetKey property for file streams to specify read offset.

```
NSInputStream *s = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:path];
[s setProperty:offset forKey:NSStreamFileCurrentOffsetKey];
```